# How to check the browser page is always on the top using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have write a test site, when user begin test, i will open a new window, and i don't want user can change the browser window, how could i check the user is always on my window, i can only thought to check whether the user is pressing the alt+tab or the mouser is leave the window use javascript. So, Are there any other better solution?Thanks!

Comment: If you get this to work, your users will hate you.

Comment: @DonRoby Check != Force. It could actually be nice if a useless window clears itself up once it's unfocused ([`window.onblur` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onblur)).

Comment: @Rob W: I quote: "i don't want user can change the browser window" - sounds like force to me.

Comment: The user is my ta's student, i want they can't to google any thing and copy past, so i want to avoid they change the window.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any other solutions.
The browsers wouldn't let you do this.
But I can't see how it would work with the solutions you have:
 - You can't set the position of the cursor, so you can't stop the mouse in leaving the window,
 - You can't stop the system in using the Alt+tab, you can only controle the browser window.

But if you're getting it work, please write your solution in this threat, thanks